# How can I get the name of the currently logged in user in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I need to display the full name of the user logged into my Drupal 7 site.

How can I do this? Where should I make the changes? I don't need PHP filter module to write a PHP line to enable as it block.

Please give me a good solution to get the logged in user's name at the top right hand side.

Comment: Where do you exactly need to show the username?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
global $user;
print $user->name;
?>
```

[These are](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7) other attributes which you can get form $user object.

Just refer this link for your updated question: http://www.victheme.com/blog/drupal-7-creating-horizontal-login-bar-without-module

Comment: see my comments. where can i add this ? i don't wish to enable to PHP filter.

Comment: @jacksantho No offence but if you're not prepared to engage in this community even a tiny bit then it's pretty bad form of you to expect people to hold your hand through your work (which I presume you're being paid for). You have steadfastly ignored others' comments asking you to mark the answers to your questions as correct, and I just don't believe that out of the 18 questions you've asked (over 70% of which have good answers) that not one of them helped you at all. If you want to take, you need to give back as well. If you don't, those that _can_ help you simply _won't_ in the future.